# CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning  Entity Framework in MVC from

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8f4P8U1a2TI

When i placed Html.DisplayNameFor() in 3rd row of html in foreach loop .It give following Error :

> CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor
>   and
>
> 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor,MvcApplication1.Models.Department>

I have double Checked html Tags . but coudnt find issue

Index View :

```
    @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Employee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div style="font-family">
    <h2>
        Index</h2>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
</div>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th>  </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>  </td>
            <td>  </td>
            <td>  @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.Name)   </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I search other posts .. could not find relevant.
Please suggest

Employee Controller

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private EmployeeContext1 db = new EmployeeContext1();

        //
        // GET: /Employee/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var employees = db.Employees.Include("Department");
            return View(employees.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Employee/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Single(e => e.Id == id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Employee/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Employee/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Employees.AddObject(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name", employee.DepartmentId);
            return View(employee);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Employee/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Single(e => e.Id == id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name", employee.DepartmentId);
            return View(employee);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Employee/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Employees.Attach(employee);
                db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(employee, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name", employee.DepartmentId);
            return View(employee);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Employee/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Single(e => e.Id == id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Employee/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Single(e => e.Id == id);
            db.Employees.DeleteObject(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Model is autoGenerated by Entity Framework

Comment: Show your `Department` class.

Comment: I have added Department class

Comment: Finally ..1. Created MVC Project from Scracth ...2.Add EF 3. Add Employee Controller ... it Worked ...there was some garbage Code which i couldnot locate unfortunatelly

Answer (score 2):

Look i have changed the answer, This will definitely work for you.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var employees = db.Employees.Include("Department");
        return View(employees);
    }
```

Why are you using BeginForm here. Remove it

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <tr> <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td> <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td> <td>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.Department.Name)
           </td> <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) | <input type="submit"  value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure wanna Delete with ID =@item.Id');"/> </td> </tr>
}
```

Hope, It will helps you.

Comment: using 2 models was mistake .. i corrected that early ... i tried what you said ... if i use @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Department> .. then First Table columns are not binding properly

Comment: By not binding properly, you mean. the department name is not getting binded, ?

Comment: it is binding .. I mean property shows in intellisense ..it is giving ambiguous call error . I think it is referring 2 assemblies . But i am not using 2 assemblies to refer

Comment: Ya i got that, you have to use Include keyword in the lambda expression. Just include Department table in the lambda expression. If you dont know, just put the action code in the question. I'll help you

Comment: I have changed my answer have a look at it. or put your controller code in your question. So, it will help me.

Comment: This code is already present in Controller .. I have put controller Code

Comment: I have changed the answer. Plaease check it

Comment: Nope . still the Same

Comment: did you removed the .ToList()

Comment: Nope .. I copied paste complete Code , removed beginForm..still same

Comment: i posted new post .. it is not issue of foriegn Key , anything you post in 3rd row . gives ambigious call error

Comment: Finally ..1. Created MVC Project from Scracth ...2.Add EF 3. Add Employee Controller ... it Worked ...there was some garbage Code which i couldnot locate unfortunatelly

Comment: Lolz :D Sorrry, i was unable to catch, I had to run. Anyways, thank god it worked. :) But restarting works everywhere.. :P

Comment: Problem i Figured out that while dealing with EF ..create , edit , details , index , delete operation should not be created manually ..Otherwise it created conflict .. that surely happened to my case ...

Comment: What, you are a newbie and manually created the views.. Use scaffolding for that, Views and actions are created automatically, you can edit them further if you want to..